# Use existing classes in prestashop module

Tags: class, module, prestashop

I am preparing a custom module for prestashop. I want to use in it some classes that exist in prestashop already (Orderdetail.php).

How can I do this? Is the code below sufficient or do I need to include something else in addition?

```
$order = new OrderDetail;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the native classes can be called like that.

```
$order_detail = new OrderDetail();
```

However to use custom classes you need to include their files in the script you want to use them.

```
include_once 'path_to_custom_class_file';

class MyModule extends Module {
    public function aMethod() {
        $myClass = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To make an instance of your module you have to use this code:

```
$mymodule = Module::getInstanceByName('mycustommodule');
```

Than you can use method of your module core. 
E.g.

```
$mymodule->myCustomMethod('x', 'y');
```