# Retrieve a product in a module prestashop

Tags: class, module, prestashop, product

I try to retrieve a product with a specific id in a custom module in prestashop.

so far i have created the controller and the view and inside the controller following a relative question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023358/use-existing-classes-in-prestashop-module/40023711#40023711) I am using the following:

```
   public function initContent()
    {

    $product = new Product();
    $this->context->smarty->assign('product',$product);
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('productcustom.tpl');
    }
```

My question is how can I call the specific product?

Comment: Is this a custom controller? You have to pass to the controller the id in some way

Comment: Yes. I declared it like this `Class testmoduleCustomProductPageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController `

Comment: Ok, and in a same way you have to pass the id to the controller, you can put in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to insert in the URL of a link or somewhere. Then use

```
$id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
```

For example, if you have a link for your module controller like this: `http://example.com/module/mymodule/mycontroller?id_product=1`

You can retrieve the id product with the code upward :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! so my url will be smth like this:

Comment: I add more infos for you :)

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos And then initialize object with `$product = new Product($id_product);`. Look at the `Product.php` constructor for additional optional parameters.

Comment: Thank you very useful! And inside the controller how will I use the $product_id?

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos Like TheDrot says ;)

Comment: @sarcom thanks it is working!  for some reason hooks inside product page dont show up but I ll find a way..